# AzMan and Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, azman

I have setup AzMan and have a few classic ASP sites that I would like to use it in. The AzMan store is setup in Active Directory. I can get it to work fine in ASP.NET and using a VBS (Visual Basic Script). My problem is that it doesn't work on classic ASP. I assume it has something to do with security. Here is the line it fails on:

```
AzManStore.Initialize 0, "msldap://domain.com/CN=BIS,CN=Program Data,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

I know the connection string is correct and it works fine with the other applications. The ASP application is running under anonymous. What I believe is happening is that the user cannot login. Is there a way to provide a username and password in the connection string?

The requirements for this site is using anonymous access, but using forms to authenticate.

Comment: A cart? Not sure what you mean. This question had nothing to do with a cart.

Comment: No, it is Authorization Manager (AzMan) Store: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897401.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to make sure that your process identity is set to a custom domain account, and not running as a local machine account like `IUSR_<servername>` or ApplicationPoolIdentity, which might not be able to bind to the AD.

Comment: That is what it was. I had to use a domain user account. Thanks.